# Forming a probability density function

Tags: probability

A  fair  coin  is  tossed  4  times  continuously.  Let  X  represent  the  number  of  times  head  appears.  Form  a probability density function for X, and find the probability of
i)  P(X=2)  ii)  P(X<=2)    iii) P(1<=X<=3)

Comment: If necessary, make a list of all the possibilities. There are $16$ of them, all equally likely. In shorthand, some of them are HHHH, HHHT, HHTH, HHTT, HTHH, and so on. Each has probability $\frac{1}{16}$. (i) Count how many of them give you $X=2$, divide by $16$. (ii) Count how many give you $X=0$, $1$, or $2$, divide by $16$. Soon you will know faster ways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want $x$ heads, you have to find the number of ways to get x heads out of 4 tosses, and this should be a simple combinatorial problem. You then divide by the total number of possible outcomes, which is $2^4$. Of course, this is assuming your coin is fair.